# Split code by semicolon

Tags: php, regex, explode

I would like to parse a source code. I read it line by line, but one line can contain more than one command.

I wonder if it is possible to split line by semicolons, but only by those, which aren't in a `'...'` or `"..."` blocks.

Comment: Why not use a [tokeniser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php)? rather than trying to write your own parser

Comment: is it possible to parse phpdoc using it aswell?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to parse phpdoc using the tokenizer.... it's designed to parse PHP files, that includes docblocks as well as code

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse a computer language will get you in trouble somewhere down the road. You need a real parser. If it is php you're parsing, use https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question: to split a line by a semi-colon not inside double or single quoation marks, you can use the following regex:

```
(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|;
```

It will find `;` exactly outside `"..."` and `'...'`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xF5eW3/1).

However, please consider using [appropriate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) [tools](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) for the task you are taking up.